# JAVA Properties To XML sorted

Tags: java, xml

I work with JAVA Properties to XML and I have code like :

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("TERMINAL_ID","1330");
    properties.put("ACTIVE_STATUS","1");
    properties.put("CARD_ACCEPT","EZ");
    properties.put("CARD_DENIED","LG,JK");
    properties.put("CARD_TIMEOUT","0");
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("./mod.xml"));
        properties.storeToXML(outStream, new java.util.Date().toString());
        outStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

why the output of data in XML file is not sorted by the time it's added to properties?

the output :

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment>Fri Oct 09 16:46:46 WIB 2015</comment>
    <entry key="CARD_DENIED">LG,JK</entry>
    <entry key="CARD_ACCEPT">EZ</entry>
    <entry key="ACTIVE_STATUS">1</entry>
    <entry key="CARD_TIMEOUT">0</entry>
    <entry key="TERMINAL_ID">1330</entry>
</properties>
```

How to made the output comes like :

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment>Fri Oct 09 16:46:46 WIB 2015</comment>
    <entry key="TERMINAL_ID">1330</entry>
    <entry key="ACTIVE_STATUS">1</entry>
    <entry key="CARD_ACCEPT">EZ</entry>
    <entry key="CARD_DENIED">LG,JK</entry>
    <entry key="CARD_TIMEOUT">0</entry>
</properties>
```

How the best way to achieve that?
Thank you.

Comment: Why should it be sorted? What difference would it make? Order among properties isn't significant. NB Your example isn't sorted either.

Comment: @EJP Because it's XML, When it's can be sorted, user can easily read and modified it. Sort by the time when data add to properties.

Comment: Well, that isn't the way they defined properties. Properties have two attributes: a key and a value. Not a time sequence. If you want that, you'll have to implement it yourself. NB There is nothing more readable about entries in a time sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The `Properties` object is a subclass of `Hashtable`, which means that the ordering of keys is essentially random.

But, the XML generation is presumably using the key traversal methods of `Map<Object, Object>` to generate the XML file, so you might be able override the key traversal methods to influence the order.

You could try this:

```
Properties p = new Properties() {
    @Override
    public Set<Object> keySet() {
        return new TreeSet<Object>(super.keySet());
    }
}
```

This is a terrible idea, because you are depending on implementation details of the `Properties` class. If you have specific requirements for the XML output, it would be better to use a proper XML binding library, like JAXB.